Regex pattern in RE2 for Apps Script
I'm trying to use the findText() function of the DocumentApp class to get the position of some text inside a Google Docs. To do so, I'm using a Regex (RE2) expression. I want it to find the following sequences: $$anyCharacterHere$$ ; basically anything enclosed in between $$ ... $$. As there might be more than one of these sequences, we have to tell the regex to match any sequence of this type without any "$" inside.
I've tried using the following:
const re2 = new RegExp("\\$\\$.*(?!\\\$)\\$\\$");
let range = docBody.findText(re2)

but it says that this is an invalid expression. I tried changing the backslashes and that kind of things, but couldn't get any further.
The goal I want to achieve is, for example, in this text:

Thi is a $$text$$ to show an $example$$ of how the $$regex$$ $$$hould$$ work.

the regex should find: $$text$$  and $$regex$$.

It is not about escaping, re2 regex does not support lookarounds.

You might try .findText("([^$]|^)\\$\\$[^$]*\\$\\$([^$]|$)"), not sure if it works though.

The argument of findText has to be a string, not a RegExp object.

You can try
`const re2 = "\$\$[^$]+\$\$";
let range = docBody.findText(re2);`

The question suggests that you need to deal with, and ignore, repeated delimiters. To save yourself a lot of trouble, I'd recommend that you switch to bracket delimiters such as {string} or <<string>>.

How about just "\\$\\$.*?\\$\\$"??

@TheMaster that will not match the right substrings. See the example in the question

Actually, the solution by @EL SRY works well enough for what I was looking for. Thanks!

With the example in the question, that regex will match $$text$$, $$ of how the $$ and $$ $$, which is not what you show as the desired result. It is now unclear what you want.

I don't mind if there are spaces in between the $$ ... $$. As I mentioned, I expect any character in between the $$ ... $$ except "$", so spaces or nothing is allowed!

Problem is that the desired results you show in the question are $$text$$ and $$regex$$, and that regex won't get that result from the sample sentence you show. Please [edit] the question and add all relevant detail there.

Actually, the solution by @EL SRY works well enough for what I was looking for. Thanks! - @Pion Developer . Thanks for your confirmation. I will post it as an answer, so that other community members who came up with the same question can see it as a reference. Also, kindly edit your post and clarify your objectives so that community members will have a clear understanding of your end goal.

Oh! Yes, @doubleunary, you're right! I'm sorry, #ELSRY but I didn't realize about that. The solution partially works, but it doesn't give the exact correct answer.

I know that using regular expressions with DocumentApp.Element.findText() is confusing. The regular expression should be written as a string rather than a RegEx object. Another thing that might be hard to understand is that not all regular expression features are supported by this method and that the \ should be escaped.
Here is the search pattern that I suggest: [^$][$]{2}[^ $]+[$]{2}. As you can see, it doesn't use \.
The below function will log all the matches.
function myFunction() {
    const body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
    const re = "[^$][$]{2}[^ $]+[$]{2}";
    let found;
    while (found = body.findText(re, found)) {
        const txt = found.getElement().asText().getText();
        if (found.isPartial()) {
            const start = found.getStartOffset();
            const end = found.getEndOffsetInclusive();
            Logger.log(txt.substring(start, end + 1));
        } else {
            Logger.log(txt);
        }
    }
}

Using the sample text included in the question:

Thi is a $$text$$ to show an $example$$ of how the $$regex$$ $$$hould$$ work.

The Execution logs showed the following:










6:20:26 PM
Notice
Execution started


6:18:58 PM
Info
$$text$$


6:18:58 PM
Info
$$regex$$


6:20:26 PM
Notice
Execution completed




Thank you! I've tried your solution and seems clean and tidy, but for a reason I don't really understand, when I try it with this text: This is an $$example text$$ to demonstrate how this regex should work. $$This text$$ must be found by regex, but not $$this one$$. Moreover this $$should$$ affect the matches, and $$this one$$ must be in too!, it does only find $$should$$. Any idea why?

@PionDeveloper Thanks for your nice words. Please bear in mnd that follow questions should be posted as a new question instead of as a comment.

Sorry for that. As it was related to the answer, I though it would be clearer to post it as a comment instead of opening a whole new question.

use re='[$]{2}[^$]+[$]{2}' to match multiple words inside $$

Regex to Find $$text text&&
Note readers: I am posting this as an answer based on the confirmation that it is indeed what the OP need, Editing the post to complete the answer as how the question turned out based on the continuous comments from the community and OP.
Capturing all segments of strings enclosed with double dollar signs $$, while having a white space before the beginning of first $$.
function myFunction() {
    const body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
    const regex = "\\s\\$\\$[^$]+\\$\\$";  

    let found;
    
    while (found = body.findText(regex, found)) {
        const txt = found.getElement().asText().getText();
        if (found.isPartial()) {
            const start = found.getStartOffset();
            const end = found.getEndOffsetInclusive();

            const matchText = txt.substring(start, end + 1);
            console.log(matchText);
        } else {
            console.log(matchText);
        }
    }
}

Sample sentence used:

Thi is a $$text$$ to show an $example$$ of how the $$regex$$
$$$hould$$ work $$detect this bro$$.

Sample Output:

Reference:

Regex
findText()


The expression should ignore triple $, too.

@Wicket I understand what you mean that it should have another requirement. however, I posted this as an answer because OP confirmed that it was what he was looking for.

Please remember that the answer should answer the question; comments can disappear anytime, and the comment history is unavailable to regular users. If you will address something not included in the question, please mention that in the answer.

I updated my answer to both satisfy OP's comment, and @Wicket suggestion. Please see the above answer and feel free to include your comment if there is more modification that is needed.
